# Where are Windows 10 default user credentials for network logins stored?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, user-accounts, credentials, credentials-manager

When I try to access any file server in my network for the first time, Windows is always trying to connect automatically with a wrong username:

*Please don't mind that the screenshots are in German. The dialog doesn't really contain much useful information, it basically just says that shown credentials are wrong.*

[image]

The email address `mail@example.org` is an old account of mine but the wrong one here and I have no idea where it is coming from. It's neither my local account (which I use to login on my machine) nor my organizations Active Directory account (which I use to access other hosts). I would like Windows to stop using it.

In the credentials store there is an entry called `*Session` which has these wrong credentials:

[image: Windows credentials Store]

The problem is, if I try to change the credentials, Windows still tries to log with these wrong credentials after a reboot.

I tried:

- Changing the credentials using the "Choose another account" option in the dialog and also checking "Save credentials".
- Changing the credentials by editing the `Session*` entry.
- Deleting the `*Session` entry. In this case no default credentials will be shown and I have to enter the user name manually.

It all works, but only until I restart.

I'm logged in with a local administrator account (which has no email accounts set up). I think I entered `mail@example.org` when setting up Windows at some point but I'm not sure where exactly.

So the question is, where are the default credentials coming from and how can I remove or change them?

---

I tried deleting *all* stored credentials, even ostensibly unrelated ones, as well as all network shares with `net use * /delete`. Additionally I verified with various other system tools, `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`, `vaultcmd /listcredentials` and `cmdkey /list`, that no credentials were stored anywhere, since some sources claimed that the credential manager may not show all entries in some cases. Unfortunately this didn't work and the `Session*` with the wrong username keeps coming back.

Comment: The issue eventually went away on its own after some years. It might was after installing a Windows update pack but I don't know for sure. It's still interesting to know where these credentials were coming from, so I'm leaving the question open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of our users and I solved the problem by using psexec from the sysinternals tools. You can use psexec to open a cmd with system user and as system user you can check and delete the stored credentials with cmdkey

Answer (score -1):

Connecting to company Wifi with Windows Credentials is what creates the windows credential *Session entry... For example if you disable your Wifi card and connect through network cable only, this entry will not be created on the next reboot.